# Extracting details from a cookie in the front end in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a authentication cookie and I was wondering if it would be possible extract data from the cookie in the asp.net part of the code (i.e in the HTML part) .I am able to pull it out in the backend using the code below

```
IPrincipal p = HttpContext.Current.User;
            // p.Identity.Name : this is what we will use to call the stored procedure to get the data and populate it


            string userid = p.Identity.Name;
            Response.Write("Welcome  " +
                p.Identity.Name);
            var dbcontext = new PrepLicensingSolution2010.DAL.LicensingEntities1();
            if (userid != null)
            {
                var user = dbcontext.commissions_proc(userid);
            }
```

But can this be done in the front end?

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for Javascript code?

Comment: So strange task at the first glance (i'm about cookies usage). Looks like you want to solve your problem artificially. Why you wan't to use cookie? Please, explain, what is source problem. Let base on what scenario you want to implement (I want <the type of user> should have possibility to <do something>).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on how the auth cookie is set. If HTTPOnly is used it cannot be accessed by javascript or (if the browser is secure) client side.

To access a cookie in Javascript just use

`var myCookieArray = document.cookie.split(";");`

And loop through the array to find the cookie you are looking for.

More info available here: http://www.w3schools.com/JS/js_cookies.asp

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
<asp:Label ID="welcome" runat="server" Text='<%= String.Format("Welcome {0}", HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name) %>'
```

Only thing is to becareful to test to see if the user is actually logged in before allowing the page to load because you COULD get a NullReferenceException if Identity.Name is null